# Sending a faulty UDP/IP datagram (on purpose) in unit test?

Tags: c#, networking, testing, network-programming, udp

I'm currently developing unit tests for a device (a radio encoder) that my company is developing.

It's possible to access various statistics via SNMP (v1 only), where you can get amongst other things the number of discarded UDP datagrams for various reasons.

I want to be able to send a datapacket wrapped in a faulty UDP header with various errors (checksum errors, wrong IP address in header etc) to make sure the error counters behave correctly.

I was not able to find any information on how to accomplish this, most highlevel networking functions I was able to find (obviously) calculate the checksum correctly and automatically.

Comment: @MikePennington Sure, I have access to both Windows and Linux. So if that would make it easier I'm all for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resort to Raw Sockets :

http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/clientserversocketnetworkcommunication8f_3.html
and
http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/clientserversocketnetworkcommunication8h.html

Just be aware of limitations : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx

> On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and Windows XP with  Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways:
>
> TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets. UDP datagrams with an
>   invalid source address cannot be sent over raw sockets. The IP source
>   address for any outgoing UDP datagram must exist on a network
>   interface or the datagram is dropped. This change was made to limit
>   the ability of malicious code to create distributed denial-of-service
>   attacks and limits the ability to send spoofed packets (TCP/IP packets
>   with a forged source IP address). A call to the bind function with a
>   raw socket for the IPPROTO_TCP protocol is not allowed. Note The bind
>   function with a raw socket is allowed for other protocols (IPPROTO_IP,
>   IPPROTO_UDP, or IPPROTO_SCTP, for example)